# Update ActiveRecord::Dirty changed? even if the new value equals the old value

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

I would like to update corresponding counters if an attribute of a record is updated. This should even happen if the new values equals the old value.

```
car.model = 'Fiesta'

car.model = 'Roadstar'
car.model_changed? # => true

car.model = 'Fiesta'
car.model_changed? # => false
```

Is it possible to setup ActiveRecord for a single Model to update the "changed?" Attribute (and even the database) if the old value equals the new value?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check out the methods in [ActiveModel::Dirty](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/master/activemodel/lib/active_model/dirty.rb) and [ActiveRecord::AttributeMethods::Dirty](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/master/activerecord/lib/active_record/attribute_methods/dirty.rb).

When you set an attribute, `write_attribute` is called and Rails decides what should happen with the `changed_attributes` list.  The code that manages this has changed recently, but in Rails 4.2 we have:

```
def save_changed_attribute(attr, old_value)
  if attribute_changed_by_setter?(attr)
    clear_attribute_changes(attr) unless _field_changed?(attr, old_value)
  else
    set_attribute_was(attr, old_value) if _field_changed?(attr, old_value)
  end
end
```

This is what clears an attribute from the `changed_attributes` list when the attribute is set back to to its old value.  You could potentially override this in your model so that every attribute set is logged to the `changed_attributes` list:

```
# In your Car model
def save_changed_attribute(attr, old_value)
  set_attribute_was(attr, old_value)
end
```